# React.js Error from adding different features and components

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, tailwind-css

```
ERROR in ./src/Pages/Download.jsx 17:0-65
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome' in '/Users/kylep/lulli/src/Pages'
ERROR in ./src/Pages/Download.jsx 18:0-64
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons' in '/Users/kylep/lulli/src/Pages'
ERROR in ./node_modules/@fortawesome/react-fontawesome/index.es.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
```

1. Added webpack
2. Uninstalled and reinstalled react-router-dom

full error:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/content-disposition/index.js 21:15-39
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '/Users/kylep/lulli/node_modules/content-disposition'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
    - install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "path": false }
ERROR in ./node_modules/cookie-signature/index.js 5:13-30
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in '/Users/kylep/lulli/node_modules/cookie-signature'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify") }'
    - install 'crypto-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "crypto": false }
ERROR in ./node_modules/destroy/index.js 15:17-41
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/Users/kylep/lulli/node_modules/destroy'
ERROR in ./node_modules/destroy/index.js 16:13-30
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in '/Users/kylep/lulli/node_modules/destroy'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify") }'
    - install 'stream-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "stream": false }
ERROR in ./node_modules/destroy/index.js 17:11-26
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'zlib' in '/Users/kylep/lulli/node_modules/destroy'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "zlib": require.resolve("browserify-zlib") }'
    - install 'browserify-zlib'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "zlib": false }
ERROR in ./node_modules/etag/index.js 20:13-30
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in '/Users/kylep/lulli/node_modules/etag'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify") }'
    - install 'crypto-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "crypto": false }
ERROR in ./node_modules/etag/index.js 21:12-31
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/Users/kylep/lulli/node_modules/etag'
ERROR in ./node_modules/express/lib/application.js 22:11-26
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in '/Users/kylep/lulli/node_modules/express/lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "http": require.resolve("stream-http") }'
    - install 'stream-http'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "http": false }

ERROR in ./node_modules/express/lib/application.js 29:14-37
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '/Users/kylep/lulli/node_modules/express/lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
    - install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "path": false }
ERROR in ./node_modules/express/lib/request.js 17:11-30
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net' in '/Users/kylep/lulli/node_modules/express/lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/express/lib/request.js 19:11-26
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in '/Users/kylep/lulli/node_modules/express/lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "http": require.resolve("stream-http") }'
    - install 'stream-http'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "http": false }
ERROR in ./node_modules/express/lib/response.js 20:11-26
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in '/Users/kylep/lulli/node_modules/express/lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "http": require.resolve("stream-http") }'
    - install 'stream-http'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "http": false }
ERROR in ./node_modules/express/lib/response.js 23:11-26
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '/Users/kylep/lulli/node_modules/express/lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
    - install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "path": false }
ERROR in ./node_modules/express/lib/utils.js 23:18-40
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'querystring' in '/Users/kylep/lulli/node_modules/express/lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "querystring": require.resolve("querystring-es3") }'
    - install 'querystring-es3'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "querystring": false }
ERROR in ./node_modules/express/lib/view.js 16:11-26
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '/Users/kylep/lulli/node_modules/express/lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
    - install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "path": false }
ERROR in ./node_modules/express/lib/view.js 17:9-22
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/Users/kylep/lulli/node_modules/express/lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/mime-types/index.js 15:14-37
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '/Users/kylep/lulli/node_modules/mime-types'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
    - install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "path": false }
ERROR in ./node_modules/mime/mime.js 1:11-26
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '/Users/kylep/lulli/node_modules/mime'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
    - install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "path": false }
ERROR in ./node_modules/mime/mime.js 2:9-22
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/Users/kylep/lulli/node_modules/mime'
ERROR in ./node_modules/send/index.js 22:9-22
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/Users/kylep/lulli/node_modules/send'
ERROR in ./node_modules/send/index.js 27:11-26
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '/Users/kylep/lulli/node_modules/send'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
    - install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "path": false }
ERROR in ./node_modules/send/index.js 29:13-30
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in '/Users/kylep/lulli/node_modules/send'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify") }'
    - install 'stream-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "stream": false }
ERROR in ./node_modules/serve-static/index.js 18:14-37
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '/Users/kylep/lulli/node_modules/serve-static'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
    - install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "path": false }
ERROR in ./node_modules/@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons/index.mjs
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/kylep/lulli/node_modules/@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons/index.mjs'
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.